# No Sound After Upgrade to 12.04 HWE

Tags: 12.04, sound, asus

Recently I have upgraded my Asus B43s from 12.04 to 12.04 HWE and have lost all audio upon start up.  When going to the sound setting, there are no devices available.  Once I run command "lspci | grep Audio" in the terminal, my audio comes back.  If I shutdown or restart, I have to do the same thing over again before the sound is available.  Is there anything that can be done to have the sound available on start up?  Below is the output from lspci | grep Audio.

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6400 Series]

Answer (score 0):

you can get a way arround by adding the command `lspci | grep Audio` to the startup applications in the **System Settings** . So it can be activated every time you log-in

Comment: Thanks.  Under what update in the system setting can you add the command? I currently have the old 12.04 classic gnome desktop instead of unity.

Comment: a quick way is to (Alt+F2) then write `gnome-session-properties` then **Add**  in the command write `lspci | grep Audio` . if it didn't show up then i think you need to install it `sudo apt-get install lspci | grep Audio `

Comment: Thanks.  Restoring the old kernel solved my issue. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1967394&page=2&p=11892141#post11892141